# String transform unicode in JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<i class="icon">&#xe672;</i>
```

the result is a icon like :  >

But when I render in vue:

```
<i class="icon">{{a}}</i>

a = '&#xe672;'
```

The result is      I got a string!

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML - tl;dr: try `<i class="icon" v-html="a"></i>`

Answer (score 1):

`a` contains the **HTML escape** of the unicode character, but that's not a valid escape sequence in JavaScript, so it's just a literal string. A quick fix is to bind `a` to the element's `v-html`, where the HTML escape sequence is valid.

Alternatively, you can modify `a` to use the appropriate JavaScript escape sequence. The equivalent of that unicode character in JavaScript with the [Unicode code point escape](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_unicode.html#sec_escape-sequences) is:

```
a = '\u{e672}'
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    a: '\u{e672}',
    b: '\u{01F638}',
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{a}} &#xe672;</div>
  <div>{{b}} &#x1F638;</div>
</div>
```

Another alternative is to use a third-party library (such as [`ent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ent)) to decode the HTML-escaped string:

```
 const ent = require('ent');
 a = ent.decode('&#xe672;');
```